# Is there anyway to query off a certain date in the rally web api?

Tags: javascript, rally

I can do the comparison after the fact, but I know it would be more effecient to filter out the data at the initial query. Is there a way to do something similar to

```
queryConfig[1] = {

        type : 'iteration',
        key  : 'iterations',
        query: 'StartDate > new Date() ',
        fetch: 'Name,TaskEstimateTotal,Resources'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to get all the iterations that start after today you could

```
queryConfig[1] = {

    type : 'iteration',
    key  : 'iterations',
    query: 'StartDate > TODAY ',
    fetch: 'Name,TaskEstimateTotal,Resources'
};
```

If you wanted to query for all Iterations that Start after today you could use our [date](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/utilities#DateTime) utilities.

```
queryConfig[1] = {

    type : 'iteration',
    key  : 'iterations',
    query: 'StartDate > '+ rally.sdk.util.DateTime.toIsoString(new Date()),
    fetch: 'Name,TaskEstimateTotal,Resources'
};
```